# Monochromatic solution to $x+y=z^2$

Tags: additive-combinatorics

Does anyone know any references/hints for the following problem?

For any $k \geq 1$ there is a threshold, $n_{0}=n_{0}(k)$ such that if $n \geq n_{0}$ then any $k$ -colouring of the first $n$ integers
contains three numbers $x, y, z \in[n]$ from the same colour class giving solution to the $x+y=z^2$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A complete answer is given by Green and Lindqvist (https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.08374). They show that $n_0(k)$ does not exist for any $k\geq 3$ but $n_0(2)$ does exist.

Answer (score 6):

Theorem 3 of [this paper](http://math.mit.edu/~csikvari/ramsey_density.pdf) by Csikvari, Gyarmati, and Sarkozy shows that $n_0(16)$ does not exist.

[These slides](https://www.math.uci.edu/~isaac/Honolulu_LuperiBaglini.pdf) contain related results and several references.